# upgrade all packages in a minion using state

Tags: salt-stack

How can I write a Salt state that will upgrade all packages installed on a system (for lab) for both centos and ubuntu?

I have an `upgrades.sls` that has the following:

```
upgrades:
  pkg.upgrade:
    - name: '*'
```

But it returns a

> State 'pkg.upgrade' was not found in SLS 'dfars.patching' Reason:
>   'pkg.upgrade' is not available.

Do I have to specify that for centos, then use `yum.pkg` and for Ubuntu to use `apt`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use pkg.uptodate for this

```
update_pkg:
  pkg.uptodate:
    - refresh : True
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because `pkg.upgrade` is an execution module, you are trying to run it from a state file. execution modules are the functions called by the salt command, and cannot be executed from `states` directly.

You can, however, use [module.run](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.module.html)  that allows [execution module](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/2015.8/ref/modules/index.html#module-provider-override) calls to be made via states,

```
upgrades:
  module.run:
    - pkg.upgrade
    ....
```

another way is to make use of something from `states.pkg`, such as, [states.pkg.uptodate](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.pkg.html#salt.states.pkg.uptodate),

```
salt.states.pkg.uptodate(name, refresh=False, pkgs=None, **kwargs)
```

> Verify that the system is completely up to date.
>
> **name:** The name has no functional value and is only used as a tracking
> reference
>
> **refresh:** refresh the package database before checking for new
> upgrades
>
> **pkgs:** list of packages to upgrade